# Node.js puppeteer - Fetching content seperated by br and store items in seperate variables

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I'm using node.js and puppeteer to get some data. How can I save the content of an element (which is divided by line break `<br>`) in two separate variables?

That's the HTML I'm looking at:

```
<table summary="">
    <tbody>
        <tr nowrap="nowrap" valign="top" align="left">
            <td nowrap="nowrap">2018-08-14<br>16:35:41</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I'm getting the content of the td like this (app.js):

```
let tableCell04;
let accepted;

tableCell04 = await page.$( 'body div table tr td' );
accepted = await page.evaluate( tableCell04 => tableCell04.innerText, tableCell04 );

console.log('Accepted: '+accepted);
```

The output in console is:

```
Accepted: 2018-08-14
16:35:41
```

But what I would like to have is storing the content which is separated by the line break in two separate variables so that I get sth like this:

```
Accepted_date: 2018-08-14
Accepted_time: 16:35:41
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hi you can use `tableCell04.innerHTML` to get the html instead of the plain text.

```js
accepted = await page.evaluate( tableCell04 => tableCell04.innerHTML, tableCell04 );

const [Accepted_date, Accepted_time] = accepted.split('<br>');
```